# Unable to edit program generated iOS plist

Tags: iphone, ios, plist

I'm creating a plist in my iOS app that's populated with some default values the first time the app runs (since the file doesn't exist). Right now I'm trying to test a case after some of that information is changed. If I open the plist file in the iPhone simulator's app's documents folder (~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/SOME-LONG-HASH/Documents/mystuff.plist) in OS X's Property List Editor, make my changes, and then save it, the iOS app can't reread it and overwrites it as if it didn't exist.

Is it not possible to edit an iOS plist or am I going about this wrong? I can't seem to find anything in Apple's docs.

For reference, I am saving an NSDictionary like this

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:dict toFile:myFilePath];
```

And accessing it like this

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:myFilePath];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dictionary only contains strings, numbers, arrays, and dictionaries, you should use the NSDictionary methods writeToFile:atomically: and initWithContentsOfFile: to save and load the data. Your problem is probably caused by Property List Editor writing your file in the XML format while NSKeyedUnarchiver uses a binary format. You can specify the type if you Save As… in the application.

Comment: I double checked and the Property List Editor saves a plist in the format that it reads it in. Just to be sure though, I opened a fresh copy generated by my app, modified the stored BOOL I was interested in changing (basically unchecked it), did Save As and made sure binary was selected. I still encounter the same problem where NSKeyedUnarchiver returns nil in the App and the plist is regenerated with the default values. I'll try the writeToFile and initWithContentsOfFile but the values in the dictionary are my own classes and all use NSCoding so I'm not sure if it will work.

Comment: If you use your own classes, you have to use archivers as you did.

Comment: A keyed archiver does not use a plist format. It uses a similar format which the editor will open, but when saving the editor will save as a plist, which the unarchiver cannot read.